How to verify and report results from a glm with family = quasibinomial?
I estimated a glm with the family = quasibinomial. My dependent variable is continuous survival rate, which ranges from 0 to 1 with (like: 0, 0,1, 0,2.....,1). My two predictors are categorical. One is species (17 species) and the other is location (2 locations). As an goal I want to see if there are differences within the species between the locations.
I calculated the survival rate: actual indivduals/target individuals
Unfortunately, it is not a balanced design. 8 of the species were planted with 72 individuals per location at the beginning of the experiment. For the other species, it is somewhat different in some cases. The individuals were divided into 8 plots, which in turn were divided into three areas. These are swales. After three years, we looked at how many of the individuals had survived. And calculated the survival rate as described. Therefore I have continuous survial rates between 0 and 1.
Is the glm with quasibinomial an appropriate methode?
Here my Outputs:
Call:
glm(formula = survival ~ species + location + 
 species:location, 
    family = quasibinomial, data = mort_24)

Coefficients:
                                                                 Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                                                        0.9694     0.4751   2.040
speciesAjuga genevensis                                          -20.5355  2281.3089  -0.009
speciesDaucus carota                                             -20.5355  2281.3089  -0.009
speciesEryngium planum                                            -0.2574     0.5419  -0.475
speciesEuphorbia seguieriana ssp. niciciana                       -2.3557     0.7120  -3.308
speciesHemerocallis lilioasphodelus                                3.4000     1.2004   2.832
speciesIris spuria                                                 1.5429     0.9351   1.650
speciesLinum perenne                                              -4.2146     0.8008  -5.263
speciesMolinia caerulea                                            1.8906     0.7201   2.626
speciesSalvia nemorosa                                             0.7013     0.5816   1.206
speciesSeseli montanum                                            -0.4408     0.5385  -0.818
speciesSilene vulgaris                                            -0.3320     0.5404  -0.614
speciesSorghastrum nutans                                         18.5967  1317.1144   0.014
speciesVernonia arkansana                                         -0.5639     0.6428  -0.877
speciesAllium aflatunense                                         -1.6625     0.5415  -3.070
speciesIris reticulata                                             0.7013     0.5816   1.206
speciesNarcissus tazetta                                           1.3751     0.6431   2.138
locationRummelsburg                                               -2.0680     0.6824  -3.030
speciesAjuga genevensis:locationRummelsburg                        2.0680  3226.2580   0.001
speciesDaucus carota:locationRummelsburg                           2.0680  3226.2580   0.001
speciesEryngium planum:locationRummelsburg                         0.5481     0.7772   0.705
speciesEuphorbia seguieriana ssp. niciciana:locationRummelsburg    3.4543     0.9628   3.588
speciesHemerocallis lilioasphodelus:locationRummelsburg           -0.4296     1.3456  -0.319
speciesIris spuria:locationRummelsburg                             1.0220     1.1873   0.861
speciesLinum perenne:locationRummelsburg                           3.2053     1.0181   3.148
speciesMolinia caerulea:locationRummelsburg                       -0.4039     0.9060  -0.446
speciesSalvia nemorosa:locationRummelsburg                         2.5491     0.8597   2.965
speciesSeseli montanum:locationRummelsburg                         2.5088     0.7780   3.225
speciesSilene vulgaris:locationRummelsburg                         1.8709     0.7714   2.426
speciesSorghastrum nutans:locationRummelsburg                      2.0680  1862.6810   0.001
speciesVernonia arkansana:locationRummelsburg                      3.1289     0.9740   3.212
speciesAllium aflatunense:locationRummelsburg                     -0.4840     0.9741  -0.497
speciesIris reticulata:locationRummelsburg                         1.4738     0.8108   1.818
speciesNarcissus tazetta:locationRummelsburg                       1.3329     0.8727   1.527
                                                                Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                                     0.041751 *  
speciesAjuga genevensis                                         0.992821    
speciesDaucus carota                                            0.992821    
speciesEryngium planum                                          0.634902    
speciesEuphorbia seguieriana ssp. niciciana                     0.000995 ***
speciesHemerocallis lilioasphodelus                             0.004777 ** 
speciesIris spuria                                              0.099472 .  
speciesLinum perenne                                            1.99e-07 ***
speciesMolinia caerulea                                         0.008875 ** 
speciesSalvia nemorosa                                          0.228398    
speciesSeseli montanum                                          0.413426    
speciesSilene vulgaris                                          0.539211    
speciesSorghastrum nutans                                       0.988740    
speciesVernonia arkansana                                       0.380691    
speciesAllium aflatunense                                       0.002237 ** 
speciesIris reticulata                                          0.228398    
speciesNarcissus tazetta                                        0.032903 *  
locationRummelsburg                                             0.002550 ** 
speciesAjuga genevensis:locationRummelsburg                     0.999489    
speciesDaucus carota:locationRummelsburg                        0.999489    
speciesEryngium planum:locationRummelsburg                      0.480905    
speciesEuphorbia seguieriana ssp. niciciana:locationRummelsburg 0.000361 ***
speciesHemerocallis lilioasphodelus:locationRummelsburg         0.749630    
speciesIris spuria:locationRummelsburg                          0.389708    
speciesLinum perenne:locationRummelsburg                        0.001726 ** 
speciesMolinia caerulea:locationRummelsburg                     0.655931    
speciesSalvia nemorosa:locationRummelsburg                      0.003147 ** 
speciesSeseli montanum:locationRummelsburg                      0.001331 ** 
speciesSilene vulgaris:locationRummelsburg                      0.015586 *  
speciesSorghastrum nutans:locationRummelsburg                   0.999115    
speciesVernonia arkansana:locationRummelsburg                   0.001388 ** 
speciesAllium aflatunense:locationRummelsburg                   0.619434    
speciesIris reticulata:locationRummelsburg                      0.069611 .  
speciesNarcissus tazetta:locationRummelsburg                    0.127213    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 0.360012)

    Null deviance: 556.23  on 623  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 228.09  on 590  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18

Thats the Anova output for the Modell.
> anova(mod, test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: quasibinomial, link: logit

Response: survival

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

                 Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                               623     556.23              
species          16  291.760       607     264.47 < 2.2e-16 ***
location          1    8.854       606     255.61 7.077e-07 ***
species:location 16   27.525       590     228.09 7.195e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


After fitting the model I calculate pairwise comparison with emmeans between the groups.
# Kontratste berechnen
emm_obj_mod <- mod |> 
  emmeans(~ location | species, regrid = "response" ) |> 
  contrast(method = "pairwise", adjust = "bonferroni") %>% 
  cld(Letters = letters)

> emm_obj_mod
species = Achnatherum calamagrostis:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.4750 1.32e-01 Inf   3.600  0.0003  a    

species = Ajuga genevensis:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.0000 1.03e-05 Inf   0.000  1.0000  a    

species = Daucus carota:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.0000 1.03e-05 Inf   0.000  1.0000  a    

species = Eryngium planum:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.3625 8.07e-02 Inf   4.492  <.0001  a    

species = Euphorbia seguieriana ssp. niciciana:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg  -0.3000 1.36e-01 Inf  -2.209  0.0272  a    

species = Hemerocallis lilioasphodelus:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.1208 4.38e-02 Inf   2.759  0.0058  a    

species = Iris spuria:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.1125 9.99e-02 Inf   1.126  0.2601  a    

species = Linum perenne:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg  -0.0708 4.46e-02 Inf  -1.588  0.1124  a    

species = Molinia caerulea:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.3500 6.62e-02 Inf   5.288  <.0001  a    

species = Salvia nemorosa:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg  -0.0542 5.83e-02 Inf  -0.929  0.3528  a    

species = Seseli montanum:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg  -0.0958 8.06e-02 Inf  -1.190  0.2342  a    

species = Silene vulgaris:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.0458 8.35e-02 Inf   0.549  0.5829  a    

species = Sorghastrum nutans:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.0000 5.93e-06 Inf   0.000  1.0000  a    

species = Vernonia arkansana:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg  -0.2125 1.33e-01 Inf  -1.599  0.1098  a    

species = Allium aflatunense:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.2958 6.22e-02 Inf   4.752  <.0001  a    

species = Iris reticulata:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.0958 6.96e-02 Inf   1.377  0.1685  a    

species = Narcissus tazetta:
 contrast             estimate       SE  df z.ratio p.value .group
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.0792 5.73e-02 Inf   1.382  0.1669  a    

significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
NOTE: If two or more means share the same grouping symbol,
      then we cannot show them to be different.
      But we also did not show them to be the same. 

But how can I be sure that model is fit in a good way?
And second: how can I report the results in a text? I want to show a graph with the significant differences between the groups. But how to write it down, especially for the glm Model?

Welcome to Cross Validated! To make it easier for others to read, please show the model summary and anova() output as text instead of in screenshots. Your screenshots don't show the actual form of the model. If you place text output between two lines each starting with three backticks (```) then it will be formatted in a way that will work with text-to-speech systems and that can be copied readily. Also, please provide information about how the survival fractions were calculated.

Hello, thanks for your respond. I edit my post and hope that the situation is now clearer.

Much easier to read, thanks! Could you please also edit the question to describe how the number of "target individuals" for eachsurvival outcome entered into the analysis? The precision of fractional data like these depends on the number of observations underlying the fractions, so one would have to know how you dealt with that to say whether the analysis is appropriate. Please provide that information by editing the question directly, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Sorry, but I'm not sure if I understand your request correctly. I should change the title of the question by writing: surivalrate after three years of 72 individuals per species and location. Is that what you meant?

The title is fine. My question is: do you have 1 data row for each individual, with a 0/1 code in survival for alive/dead after 3 years? Or are your survival outcome values themselves fractional? You seem to have 624 rows of data, which aren't enough for 72 individuals for each of 17 species at 2 locations. The basic R anova() function can give misleading results if the data aren't completely balanced.

Okay, i got it. :) Are the contrasts which calculated whit emmeans also a problem with an unbalanced design?

The overall approach is OK, but you need to deal with a few issues.
First, it seems that you have survival fractions calculated for each swale as the survival outcome. A binomial model needs to know how many individuals were associated with each fraction. The reason is that a fraction of 0.25 is a lot more reliable if it's based on 400 individuals than if it's only based on 4.
If you have fractional survival values then you also need to provide a weights argument specifying the total number of corresponding individuals. I don't see a weights argument in your function call. See the "Details" on the family help page.
I suspect that the low quasi-binomial dispersion parameter (0.36) estimate is related to the lack of a weights argument. Off hand, that lower-than-binomial dispersion seems consistent with about 3 animals per swale, which is about what you have. In practice, that might end up being close to what you would get with a weights argument. But why not provide the software with the actual numbers so that it can properly account for different numbers of plants per swale?
Second, there are very large standard errors for 3 of the species coefficients along with the corresponding interaction coefficients. That suggests that you have near-complete separation, possibly due to something like complete survival (or complete death) in one of the two locations for each of those species. This page and its many links describe what that means and different ways to deal with it.
The emmeans package uses the standard errors and covariances of the regression coefficient estimates to perform its tests. Those are unreliable when there is complete or near-complete separation. It's possible to perform likelihood-ratio tests instead. If this separation problem remains after you have dealt with the weights issue, then you might consider dealing with those 3 species separately and restricting the model and emmeans contrasts to the other 14.
Third, the default of the basic anova() function in R is a Type I anova with "Terms added sequentially (first to last)." That can be a problem if the design isn't balanced. The car package has an Anova() function (note the capital "A") that has a more reliable default.
The emmeans contrasts don't have that problem, as they are based on the variances and covariances of the coefficient estimates. Without specifying the numbers of individuals in the weights argument, however, those variances and covariances won't be as reliable as they could be.
Fourth, if multiple species are planted into the same plot/swale, then there might be correlations in survival among the species within the plots/swales. Without independence among observations, the modeled estimates (based on the independence assumption) might not be correct. That's a typical use case for a mixed model with plots/swales as random effects.
Modified model
Removing 3 species with complete survival or complete death and adding weights for the observations provided the following model. There is slight overdispersion versus a strict binomial model, which one might explect. Anova() from the car package shows that there are differences among species and between the 2 sites, and that the differences between sites differ among species (interaction).
With such a large number of coefficients, it probably makes sense to show the full set of model coefficients in the supplementary on-line material that currently accompanies many scientific publication.
If the differences between sites for each species are the major interest, those results via the emmeans package should be shown as a table in the main text. The "bonferroni" correction for the multiple comparisons, although simple, is unnecessarily conservative. I think that the "holm" test, which provides more power with the same protection from Type I error, is also available in that package.
As the values shown seem to be differences of survival fractions, including the actual survival estimates for each species at each location, in the table or in a graphical display, would be important to the reader.
Call:
glm(formula = survival ~ species + location + species:location, 
    family = quasibinomial, data = mort_24_filtered, weights = target_values)

Coefficients:
                                                                Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                                                     -0.69315    0.27649  -2.507
speciesNarcissus tazetta 'Falconet'                              3.10673    0.47042   6.604
speciesIris reticulata 'Harmony'                                 2.34607    0.39675   5.913
speciesHemerocallis lilioasphodelus                              5.06260    1.20523   4.201
speciesIris spuria 'Imperial Bronze'                             3.20545    0.79210   4.047
speciesLinum perenne                                            -2.55205    0.73968  -3.450
speciesSalvia nemorosa 'Caradonna'                               2.36383    0.45158   5.235
speciesSeseli montanum                                           1.13521    0.37502   3.027
speciesEryngium planum 'Blaukappe'                               1.40510    0.39164   3.588
speciesSilene vulgaris                                           1.33055    0.38928   3.418
speciesEuphorbia seguieriana ssp. niciciana                     -0.69315    0.62847  -1.103
speciesAchnatherum calamagrostis 'Algaeu'                        1.66255    0.57626   2.885
speciesMolinia caerulea 'Heidebraut'                             3.48154    0.57536   6.051
speciesVernonia arkansana                                        1.09861    0.53740   2.044
locationRummelsburg                                             -2.55205    0.73968  -3.450
speciesNarcissus tazetta 'Falconet':locationRummelsburg          1.74790    0.88527   1.974
speciesIris reticulata 'Harmony':locationRummelsburg             1.97563    0.83385   2.369
speciesHemerocallis lilioasphodelus:locationRummelsburg          0.01161    1.43660   0.008
speciesIris spuria 'Imperial Bronze':locationRummelsburg         1.50608    1.26487   1.191
speciesLinum perenne:locationRummelsburg                         3.68936    1.09255   3.377
speciesSalvia nemorosa 'Caradonna':locationRummelsburg           3.03313    0.92555   3.277
speciesSeseli montanum:locationRummelsburg                       3.07939    0.83458   3.690
speciesEryngium planum 'Blaukappe':locationRummelsburg           1.03217    0.83888   1.230
speciesSilene vulgaris:locationRummelsburg                       2.35495    0.83277   2.828
speciesEuphorbia seguieriana ssp. niciciana:locationRummelsburg  3.93834    1.21541   3.240
speciesAchnatherum calamagrostis 'Algaeu':locationRummelsburg    0.48403    1.27208   0.381
speciesMolinia caerulea 'Heidebraut':locationRummelsburg         0.15179    0.93395   0.163
speciesVernonia arkansana:locationRummelsburg                    3.61292    1.12307   3.217
                                                                Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                                     0.012484 *  
speciesNarcissus tazetta 'Falconet'                             9.96e-11 ***
speciesIris reticulata 'Harmony'                                6.11e-09 ***
speciesHemerocallis lilioasphodelus                             3.14e-05 ***
speciesIris spuria 'Imperial Bronze'                            5.99e-05 ***
speciesLinum perenne                                            0.000606 ***
speciesSalvia nemorosa 'Caradonna'                              2.41e-07 ***
speciesSeseli montanum                                          0.002593 ** 
speciesEryngium planum 'Blaukappe'                              0.000365 ***
speciesSilene vulgaris                                          0.000681 ***
speciesEuphorbia seguieriana ssp. niciciana                     0.270582    
speciesAchnatherum calamagrostis 'Algaeu'                       0.004077 ** 
speciesMolinia caerulea 'Heidebraut'                            2.77e-09 ***
speciesVernonia arkansana                                       0.041431 *  
locationRummelsburg                                             0.000606 ***
speciesNarcissus tazetta 'Falconet':locationRummelsburg         0.048866 *  
speciesIris reticulata 'Harmony':locationRummelsburg            0.018189 *  
speciesHemerocallis lilioasphodelus:locationRummelsburg         0.993556    
speciesIris spuria 'Imperial Bronze':locationRummelsburg        0.234321    
speciesLinum perenne:locationRummelsburg                        0.000789 ***
speciesSalvia nemorosa 'Caradonna':locationRummelsburg          0.001119 ** 
speciesSeseli montanum:locationRummelsburg                      0.000248 ***
speciesEryngium planum 'Blaukappe':locationRummelsburg          0.219102    
speciesSilene vulgaris:locationRummelsburg                      0.004868 ** 
speciesEuphorbia seguieriana ssp. niciciana:locationRummelsburg 0.001271 ** 
speciesAchnatherum calamagrostis 'Algaeu':locationRummelsburg   0.703727    
speciesMolinia caerulea 'Heidebraut':locationRummelsburg        0.870960    
speciesVernonia arkansana:locationRummelsburg                   0.001377 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 1.223159)

    Null deviance: 1367.04  on 543  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  677.58  on 516  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6

Here the Output of the ANOVA
> Anova(mod, test="Wald")
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: survival
                 Df   Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
species          13 237.673  < 2.2e-16 ***
location          1  13.896  0.0001932 ***
species:location 13  53.259  8.145e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 

And here the pairwise comparisons with emmeans:
> emm_obj_mod <- mod %>% 
+   emmeans(~ location | species, regrid = "response") %>%   
+   contrast(method = "pairwise", adjust = "bonferroni") 
> emm_obj_mod
species = Allium aflatunense 'Purple Sensation':
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.2958 0.0662 Inf   4.466  <.0001

species = Narcissus tazetta 'Falconet':
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.0845 0.0509 Inf   1.660  0.0969

species = Iris reticulata 'Harmony':
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.0935 0.0624 Inf   1.499  0.1340

species = Hemerocallis lilioasphodelus:
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.1259 0.0470 Inf   2.679  0.0074

species = Iris spuria 'Imperial Bronze':
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.1125 0.1196 Inf   0.941  0.3468

species = Linum perenne:
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg  -0.0708 0.0475 Inf  -1.492  0.1357

species = Salvia nemorosa 'Caradonna':
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg  -0.0542 0.0620 Inf  -0.873  0.3826

species = Seseli montanum:
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg  -0.1163 0.0838 Inf  -1.387  0.1656

species = Eryngium planum 'Blaukappe':
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.3625 0.0859 Inf   4.221  <.0001

species = Silene vulgaris:
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.0458 0.0888 Inf   0.516  0.6059

species = Euphorbia seguieriana ssp. niciciana:
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg  -0.3000 0.2154 Inf  -1.393  0.1636

species = Achnatherum calamagrostis 'Algaeu':
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.4750 0.1971 Inf   2.411  0.0159

species = Molinia caerulea 'Heidebraut':
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg   0.3462 0.0696 Inf   4.971  <.0001

species = Vernonia arkansana:
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Dahlem - Rummelsburg  -0.2125 0.1545 Inf  -1.375  0.1691


Thank you very much for you help!

@y.tu.b I will copy your updated model (currently a deleted answer) into the end of this answer and add a few more pointers.

Thank you very much, this is really helpful to me!
